# CodeIgniter 3 impossible load php file in ajax

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I created view

`application/views/admin/importexport/import.php`

This view I define in controller:

```
/**
 * Add Import
 */
public function add_import()
{
    $data['title'] = trans("add_page");
    
    $this->load->view('admin/includes/_header', $data);
    $this->load->view('admin/importexport/import', $data);
    $this->load->view('admin/includes/_footer');
}
```

Content loading correct.

Now here I put script form select file and below I add ajax post script:

```
$('#upload_form').on('submit', function(event){

    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url:"upload.php",
      method:"POST",
      data:new FormData(this),
      dataType:'json',
      contentType:false,
      cache:false,
      processData:false,
      success:function(data)
      {
        if(data.error != '')
        {
          $('#message').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">'+data.error+'</div>');
        }
        else
        {
          $('#process_area').html(data.output);
          $('#upload_area').css('display', 'none');
        }
      }
    });

  });
```

This script post data to upload.php

What is issue?
When I try post data then is no reaction to upload.php. I try put this file upload.php in root public_html also in application also in application/views etc. But still not work.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you should be able to call it like so:-

```
$.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url  : "<?php echo base_url(); ?>/controllerName/FunctionName"
      });
```

OR

```
  $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url  : "<?php echo site_url(); ?>/controllerName/FunctionName"
  });
```

**Note:-**
But this depends a little bit on your url structure and whether or not you got rid of index.php in the url structure. In that case the url would be `/index.php/controllerName/FunctionName`

Comment: I try add  in controller function  /**
     * Map csv
     */
    public function map_csv()
    {   }  then I paste {} my code upload.php then I change  in ajax event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: '<?php echo site_url("importexport_controller/map_csv")?>',
      method:"POST",
      data:new FormData(this),  but still no button reaction

Comment: can you use `enctype='multipart/form-data'`

Comment: or check response in console.

Comment: yes in form I use this:   <form method="post" id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="col-md-6" align="right">Select File</div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <input type="file" name="file" id="csv_file" />
                </div>
                <br /><br /><br />
                <div class="col-md-12" align="center">
                  <input type="submit" name="upload_file" id="upload_file" class="btn btn-primary" value="Upload" />
                </div>
              </form>